# View does not exist in module reviews.views

Tags: python, django

So I am getting this error in django

```
Exception Value:  Could not import reviews.views.get_user_review. View does not exist in module reviews.views.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in get_callable, line 118
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'feed.views.home'),
    url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^logged-in/$', 'custom_user.views.fb_loggedin'),

    #url(r'^review/get/(?P<userid>.+?)/$', 'reviews.views.get_user_reviews_json'),

    url(r'^rating/add/(?P<actor>.+?)/(?P<target>.+?)/(?P<category>.+?)/(?P<rating>.+?)/$', 'rating.views.add_rating'),
    url(r'^rating/get/(?P<userid>.+?)/$', 'rating.views.get_user_ratings'),     

)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

To remove the error, I've commented everything related to reviews app. But the error still exists. Here's the reviews.views

```
'''
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import Reviews
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.core import serializers

def user_review(userid):
    user = User.objects.get(id = userid)
    reviews  = Reviews.objects.filter(subject_user=user).select_related('user')
    return reviews
    #HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/javascript')

def get_user_reviews_json(userid):
    reviews = user_review(userid)
    data = serializers.serialize("json", reviews)
    return data
'''
```

**EDIT:**

The function `get_user_reviews_json` was earlier defined as `get_user_review` and i forgot to update the urls.py from `get_user_review` to `get_user_reviews_json` and thus got the error. but then i updated it and still the error prevails. i then commented out everything as you can see, but still the same error.

Comment: `get_user_review` - from the code you have shown does not seem to be a valid view /package name. Did you mean `get_user_reviews_json` instead? Also, you forgot the `request` parameter in the views?

Comment: The function `get_user_reviews_json` was earlier defined as `get_user_review` and i got the error. but then i updated it and still the error prevails. i then commented out everything as you can see, but still the same error. Lemme try with the `request` parameter as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your view should take a request object to respond to web requests. So your function should look something like below:

```
def get_user_reviews_json(request, userid):
    reviews = user_review(userid)
    data = serializers.serialize("json", reviews)
    return Response(data)  #from rest_framework.response import Response
```

Again, each view function takes an HttpRequest object as its first parameter, which is typically named request.I hope it helps.